# How would one go about creating a desktop animated character

Tags: windows, animation

I have a bunch of animations saved in gif format. I'd like to create a program that will randomly select one of these animations to play every X amount of time. I want these animations play **over the desktop** (not in front of the windows start bar but over it) but **not** over other programs.

I'm looking to create something like Microsoft Word's *Clippy* but over the desktop. How would one go about doing something like this? Should it be done in C#? C++? Can I use *any* language? If yes what is the trick for creating something outside a rendering window?

Comment: Have you noticed, that the taskbar is in front of applications in the Z-order? There is no position in the Z-order that is in front of the taskbar, but behind application windows. You are asking to solve the impossible.

Comment: @IInspectable Edited my question regarding the start bar issue